# Trying to extend an EJB from a Generic Class: IllegalArgumentException The Argument {0} is not a valid local client view for the EJB {1}

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic12c

I am trying to extend an EJB from a generic class as follows:

1. My Abstract Generic Class:

   ```
   public abstract class CrudDAO<T> {

        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MYPU")
        protected EntityManager em;

        protected Class<T> entityClass;

        public int count() {
             Query count = em.createQuery("select count(u) from " +     entityClass.getSimpleName() + " u");
             return Integer.parseInt(count.getSingleResult().toString());
        }

        public T create(T entity){
             em.persist(entity);
             return entity;
       }

       public T update(T entity){
           return em.merge(entity);
       }

       public void delete(int id) {
           T entity = em.find(entityClass, id);
           em.remove(entity);
       }

       public T find(int id){
           return em.find(entityClass, id);
       }

       public List<T> findAll(Integer page, Integer maxRecords) {
           Query q = em.createQuery("select u from " + entityClass.getSimpleName() + " u");
           if (page != null && maxRecords != null) {
               q.setFirstResult((page - 1) * maxRecords);
               q.setMaxResults(maxRecords);
           }
           return q.getResultList();
       }

       public<V> List<V> executeListNamedQuery(String name){
           return em.createNamedQuery(name).getResultList();
       }

       public<V> List<V> executeListNamedQuery(String name, Map<String,Object> params){
           Query q = em.createNamedQuery(name);
           for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : params.entrySet()) {
               q.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
           }
           return q.getResultList();
       }

       public<V> V executeSingleNamedQuery(String name){
           List<V> lista = em.createNamedQuery(name).getResultList();
           if(!lista.isEmpty()){
               return lista.get(0);
           }
           return null;
       }

       public<V> V executeSingleNamedQuery(String name, Map<String,Object> params){
           Query q = em.createNamedQuery(name);
           for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : params.entrySet()) {
               q.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
           }
           List<V> lista = q.getResultList();
           if(!lista.isEmpty()){
               return lista.get(0);
           }
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```
2. My EJB logic

   ```
   @Stateless
   public class UsuarioDAO extends CrudDAO<UsuarioEntity>{
       public UsuarioDAO() {
           this.entityClass = UsuarioEntity.class;
       }
   }
   ```
3. My entity only has getters and setters
4. I have another EJB that injects `UsuarioDAO` and exposes a method over a interface to a Restfull service.

   ```
   @Stateless
   public class AuthBean implements IAuthServiceBean {

       @Inject
       private UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO;

       @Override
       public UsuarioEntity agregarUsuario(UsuarioEntity usuario) {
           return usuarioSpadiesDAO.create(usuario);
       }
   }
   ```

My Restfull service calls agregarUsuario Injecting AuthBean. My problem is when I try to access the Restfull service it throws this exception:

```
The argument package.to.dao.CrudDAO is not a valid local client view for the EJB UsuarioDAO(Application: <MyEarSnapShot>, EJBComponent: <MyWarSnapshot>)
```

I have an EAR that contains a WAR and an EJB component. EJB component is a dependency of WAR Component. Restfull Services are in the WAR component, other stuffs are in EJB component.

I'm using WebLogic 12c for deployment.

Comment: Please show the structure of your ear-module, and how the war module includes the ejb-module (interface api, or the ejb-jar dependency?)

Comment: Any progress with this issue? I'm experiencing the same issue. It suddenly popped up on my Weblogic 12.1.3 instance without any code changes... A complete reinstall of Weblogic "fixed" the issue, but for how long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing patch 19533331 solved the issue for me.

19533331    Dependency injection    12.1.3.0.3  CDI does not consider all superclasses and interfaces of an EJB when processing EJBs.